# Why JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) fails with a simple dictionary?

Tags: javascript

Instead of showing me the dictionary this gives an error when parsing the string.

```js
var mycode = "var data = " + JSON.stringify({"a":"b"}) + "; alert(JSON.parse(data));"
eval(mycode);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do

```
"var data = " + JSON.stringify({"a":"b"}) + ";
```

You end up with the string

```
var data = {"a":"b"};
```

Note that there are no quotes around the object, and when that string is passed to `eval` it's evaluated as an object, not a string.
JSON strings are also valid JavaScript objects if not quoted as strings, you have to actually add quotes

```
"var data = '" + JSON.stringify({"a":"b"}) + "';
```

which will give you

```
var data = '{"a":"b"}';
```

When you pass a JavaScript object to `JSON.parse` it's converted to a string, and the string representation of an object being `[object, Object]`, if errors out on the `o` letter, as it's not an object that can be parsed to JSON.

It's not that `stringify` doesn't create a string, it does, it's just that the string of javascript you're creating has an object as the value of the `data` variable, not a string, and when eval'ing the code it's trying to parse that object with `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score -3):

I think the problem is you expect **alert** to behave like **console.log**, it would help you to write:

```
var mycode = "var data = " + JSON.stringify({"a":"b"}) + "; console.log(JSON.parse(data));"

eval(mycode);
```

Note that this will print the output in the console, not prompt you with an alert.